# How do I get it to repeat the statement if nothing is entered, in python?

Tags: python

```
while num_students < 0:
   num_students = int(input("How many students are you entering? "))
```

How do I get it to repeat the question if nothing is entered by the user (so they just go enter), in python?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a slightly more general approach, if only to avoid a `ValueError` if the user enters a string that can't be converted to an `int`.

```
while True:
    answer = input("How many ... ")
    try:
        num_students = int(answer)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if num_students >= 0:
        break
```

An infinite loop with an explicit `break` is a common Python idiom used in place of the nonexistent `do-while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_students = -1

while num_students < 0:
    try:
        num_students = int(input("How many students are you entering? "))
    except:
        print "Please enter an integer greater than or equal to 0"
```

I would recommend this code.  It avoids flow of control statements like "break" and "continue" and will not crash if a string or other invalid input is entered.  Avoiding flow of control statements makes a program easier to analyze which is helpful for determining its speed or security.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it works by adding a condition to the while.

```
while num_students < 0 and not num_students:
   num_students = int(input("How many students are you entering? "))
```